# Webstorm "Go to declaration" W/ require.js

Tags: javascript, webstorm

If code files begin with the class declaration, Webstorm picks it up in other files. Meaning that in B.js that references my class in A.js, I can "Go to Declaration", and it opens A.js.

**A.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       ...
}
```

**B.js**

```
let routes = (
    <Route handler={App} path="/">
);
```

**But** if A.js has require statements at the beginning, the "Go to Declaration" can no longer find the reference when I'm editing in B.js.

**A.js W/ Require**

```
let React = require('react');
let Router = require('react-router');
let { Link, Route, NotFoundRoute, RouteHandler } = Router;

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       ...
}
```

Is there some way to configure WebStorm to pickup the references after the require statements?

*Edit: I'm using WebStorm 10.0.4.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you mean you can navigate to a.js (with require) from b.js when cmd-click on App? Works fine for me...

Comment: Correct. WebStorm is also having issues picking up references to the class as well, via alt+F7. But only in the files that are requiring files.

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. But can you please try WebStorm 11 EAP, may be it will work better for you: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/08/webstorm-11-eap-142-4148/